# How to Join Two Colliding SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

If I have two `SKSpriteNode` objects, one circle and one square, traveling at each other at high speeds, is there a way to make them stick to each other and stop moving when they collide? Typically, `didBeginContact` method is not fast enough at detecting a collision to set their physics bodies' velocities equal to zero before they've already bounced apart by ~30 pixels. Is there a way I can join the two `SKSpriteNodes`? Thanks (:

Comment: yeah use s a physics pinjoint on collision detection and stuff

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is going crazy, but my initial idea is to play around with magnetic fields.  You could make a [magnetic field](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/magneticField) and give one of the bodies some [charge](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/charge) and then the physics simulation will naturally try and hold those two things together.